# Applying tuple to dataframe doesnt preserve type

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
        SAMPLE_ID  ROW  COL  Field  Value
Index
1              1    1    1   1103  61.62
2              1    1    1   1104 -24.60
3              1    1    1   1105 -50.22
```

What I'd like is a series of tuples of the data.

But when I enter:

```
>> df.apply(tuple, axis = 1)
```

I get this series, which converts ints to floats.

```
Index
1             (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1103.0, 61.62)
2             (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1104.0, -24.6)
3             (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1105.0, -50.22)
```

I'd like the tuples to maintain their type, ending up with a series like this

```
Index
1             (1, 1, 1, 1103, 61.62)
2             (1, 1, 1, 1104, -24.6)
3             (1, 1, 1, 1105, -50.22)
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you enter `df.iloc[0]` what type does it show?

Comment: Are you sure the dtype is not float already? what does `df.info()` show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hack is to set the dtype to object before doing the apply:

```
In [11]: df.astype(object).apply(tuple, axis=1)
Out[11]:
0     (1, 1, 1, 1, 1103, 61.62)
1     (2, 1, 1, 1, 1104, -24.6)
2    (3, 1, 1, 1, 1105, -50.22)
dtype: object
```

---

Otherwise when creating a Series (for each row) pandas forces it to be the "smallest" type, in this case int64 + float64 becomes float64, hence all the values are made floats:

```
In [12]: df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype, axis=1)
Out[12]:
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
dtype: object
```